# How to sort the tabs inside IconTabBar UI control in SAP UI5

Tags: sapui5

I have to sort the tabs within IconTabBar control alphabetically. I have searched for the sorting functions in controller but those are triggered after an UI event.
whereas i need to make those sorting whenever the second view loads(or when we travel to second view).
Can anyone please suggest how to achieve this in view itslef( Note:- i'm using XML view).below is the view code for the same.

```
<IconTabBar id="idIcontabs" items='{ProModel>/results}'
            showSelection="true" stretchContentHeight="true" class='styleForIconTab'>
            <items>
              <IconTabFilter text="{ProModel>Grpname}">
```

Thanks a lot in advance..!!!

Regards,
Ranjan R

Comment: It isn't clear what is a "second view". Do you want to just sort the tabs by their name?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it was tabular data i wanted to sort i achieved it using "sorter" for the entity in the model. and it rendered me the view with the data in sorted format.
Thanks all who provided their time to answer this question.